# Adding Handler to htaccess causes file to download, removing Add Handler directive causes internal server error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm stuck trying to figure out what directives my htaccess file for a directory needs. To give a little background, I was messing around with AddType and AddHandler to try to get html files to run php in them. I was adding directives like:

```
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
```

and

```
    AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php .html
```

That didn't work, so I tried adding handlers as well:

```
    AddHandler x-httpd-php .php .html
```

and

```
   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html
```

That still didn't give me what I wanted so I tried many combinations, like:

```
   AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
   AddHandler php-script .php .html
```

I even tried combinations with SetHandler

```
   AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
   AddHandler php-script .php .html
   SetHandler application/x-httpd-php .php html
```

I tried every imaginable combination of AddType and AddHandler found on the web.

!===== This is important ======!
I realized that its not good practice to have php run your html files just so you can run php in the html. I am no longer trying to do that. The only reason I'm posting this part above is to give you an idea on some things I've changed. These changes were made to the htaccess file at a directory above the root.
!==============================!

Now that I'm no longer trying to run my php in html files I cleared the AddType, AddHandler, and SetHandler directives from the htaccess file. But now I get an internal server error when trying to run php files.

So I tried putting some stuff back. If I had a handle, the browser now downloads the php instead of running it.

I should note that any php running below the directory I changed works fine. But everything in that directory or subdirectory of that directory has this same problem with php files.

I have tried deleting the htaccess file in that directory, but that does not work, I get an internal error.

If I turn Override off, I get an internal error.

Something I changed is persisting in that directory and I'm wondering how to either

a. turn it off
b. add the correct handler to that htaccess file so that php files are run again (like they are on the rest of the server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized I left this up unanswered after I solved the problem. If someone has a similar problem and is reading this : Check the permissions on all associated folders. I can't remember the specifics but one of the directories involved (I believe it was the htaccess directory) had permissions that persisted after changing some things and then changing them back.

Answer (score 0):

I did have the exact same issue so I deleted all the content of .htaccess and started trying only with handlers until I figured it out. My local .htaccess copy had the following SetHandler:

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php5-3 .php
```

In my case it worked after changing it to:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

It seems the whole trick is only the handler, I tried this solution in 2 different servers with different configurations and in both cases just changing AddHandler worked. If this doesn't work for you try a different handler for php.

Hope it helps.